# Limit of the sequences $a_n~=(1/n)^{(\sin(1/n))}$ and $b_n~=~(\sin(1/n))^{(1/n)}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is  the limit of the sequence $a_n~=(1/n)^{(\sin(1/n))}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $  and

$b_n~=~(\sin(1/n))^{(1/n)}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $ ?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean

Comment: both limites are $1$

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong:

1)$a_n = (1/n)^{\sin(1/n)}$.

Note: $ \sin(t) \le t$ for $ t \in (0,\infty)$.

$|\log a_n| = |\sin(1/n)\log(1/n)| \le$

$|(1/n)\log (1/n)| = |\frac{\log n}{n}|.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\log a_n| = 0.$

$\rightarrow:$ $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 1.$

2)$b_n = (\sin(1/n))^{1/n}$.

Since

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n} = 1,$

for $n \in \mathbb{N} $ large enough we have:

$(1/2) \le \dfrac {\sin(1/n)}{1/n}$.

$c_n:= [(1/2)(1/n)]^{1/n} \le b_n$

$\le (1/n)^{1/n} =: d_n$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_n = 1 \le$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n \le $

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_n = 1.$

$\rightarrow:$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = 1$.

Note :

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^{1/n} =1$ and

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n} = 1$.

Comment: Your argument in 2) doesn't work - $(1/n)^{1/n}$ approaches $1$ from _beneath_, so the fact that $b_n\leq (1/n)^{1/n}$ tells you nothing about its limit behavior.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Steven.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n} =1.$ We also know $x/2 \le \sin x \le x$ for small positive $x.$ Thus for $n$ large,

$$\left (\frac{1}{2n}\right )^{1/n} \le (\sin(1/n))^{1/n} \le \left (\frac{1}{n}\right )^{1/n}.$$

Since $2^{1/n} \to 1$ and $n^{1/n} \to 1,$ the sequences on the left and right $\to 1.$ By the squeeze theorem, so does the middle sequence. Your other sequence can be handled the same way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\implies \log(a_n)=-{\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\log(n)$$ Now, using Taylor series ( or equivalents) for large $n$ leads to $$\log(a_n)=\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)\log(n)$$ from which you can easily conclude.

Your turn for the next one